# How to get and use user location in flutter and suggest a place to user

Tags: flutter, google-api

I'm currently working on a flutter project and I want to get the user's location and suggest a place for a user. Not restaurants or etc. Given by google API. I  want to put my own suggested place to the user

Thank you in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the user's location, you might use https://pub.dev/packages/location
With their geolocation, you can query your own suggest dataset and show to the users

Comment: can you give me an example on how to query in geolocation?